# Php combine the values of two array objects

Tags: php

I have a oject that contains:and I want combine the content of [0][locationName and [1][locationName into another object/variable so the content would be "Weymouth and Bournemouth". I know there are similar questions on here but my keys in the array have the same name. How would this be done?

```
[destination] => stdClass Object
   (
   [location] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [locationName] => Weymouth
          )

      [1] => stdClass Object
      (
        [locationName] => Bournemouth
      )
  )
)
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: may be this could do your task `$destination->location[0]->locationName." and ".$destination->location[1]->locationName.`

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Show us the code for you attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the reference to `$destination` as an object then perhaps you can try like this:

```
$arr=$destination->location;
$tmp=array();

foreach( $arr as $index => $obj )$tmp[]=$obj->locationName;

$tmp=implode(' and ',$tmp ); // do something with $tmp
```

Assuming I recreated the original object correctly

```
$obj=(object)array(
    'destination' => (object)array(
        'location'  =>  array(
            (object)array('locationName'=>'Weymouth'),
            (object)array('locationName'=>'Bournemouth')
        )
    )
);
```

The above produces a structure like this:

```
[destination] => stdClass Object
    (
        [location] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [locationName] => Weymouth
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [locationName] => Bournemouth
                    )

            )

    )

$destination=$obj->destination;

pre( $obj );

$arr=$destination->location;
$tmp=array();

foreach( $arr as $index => $obj )$tmp[]=$obj->locationName;

$tmp=implode(' and ',$tmp ); // do something with $tmp
echo $tmp;  // --> outputs Weymouth and Bournemouth
```

Comment: Hi all, the code I was trying is/was the same as RamRaider just posted "$array1=$destination->location;
$temp=array();

foreach( $array1 as $index => $obj )$temp[]=$obj->locationName;

$temp=implode(' and ',$temp ); // do something with $tmp

print_r ($temp); But I get the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Hi and again thanks for your help, Your code works providing there is only one destination location. As you can see this is where a train is split, one half to destination 1 and the other half to destination 2. code as is does write "Weymouth and Bournemouth" but writes "and" to all the other destination fields and not the destination name if there is only one.